# Python Fuzzywuzzy does not give a similarity of 100 for identical terms

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

Why is Fuzzywuzzy library not giving me back proper results for terms which are identical?
I would assume a similarity of 100, or at least 95 if 100 is not working. Am I missing something?
Maybe there's a better fuzzy matching algorithm?

My code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import pandas as pd

# creating a data frame
df1 = pd.read_csv('List1.csv', sep=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('List2.csv', sep=';')

NAME_MATCH = []
similarity = []

for i in df2.NAME_LIST2:
        ratio = process.extract(i, df1.NAME_LIST1, limit=1)
        NAME_MATCH.append(ratio[0][0])
        similarity.append(ratio[0][2])

df2['NAME_MATCH'] = pd.Series(NAME_MATCH)
df2['similarity'] = pd.Series(similarity)
print(df2.head())
df2.to_csv('output.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

The strange thing is that a different wording has a higher similarity than identical findings.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `process.extract(i, df1.NAME_LIST1, limit=1)`, exactly what do you think this means? What do you think will be the values of `i` and `df1.NAME_LIST1` each time through the loop? Did you try to check what result you get in `ratio`, each time through the loop, after doing this? Did you try to read the [documentation](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz#process) in order to understand what the result from `process.extract` should look like?

Comment: from what I read out of the tutorials limit=1 means that I will get back the top (most accurate) result from "i" being searched in the dataframe_1.

Comment: Please read [mre] and show code that we can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, in order to reproduce the problem. I.e.: instead of reading from CSVs, hard-code some example data.

Comment: ok, I should've used similarity.append(ratio[0][1]) instead of similarity.append(ratio[0][2]). sorry for this unnecessary question.